# Android Studio doesn't open AVD and SDK Manager - "android.bat" not found

Tags: android-studio

Short Story - Android Studio doesn't open AVD and SDK Manager all of a sudden. It throws an error `4:18:46 PM ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified:..`

Long Story - This may sound impossible but here is what has happened. I have been using Studio for a week now and have been running a few AVDs since day 1. Today, I opened Studio again, executed my app on one AVD, closed AVD, made some changes, reexcuted my app and waited for available AVD dialog box to open.. but instead got above mentioned error. Just like that. I didn't do anything else. It was working like a minute ago. I checked various related questions on stackoverflow but couldn't solve it. Just thought of mentioning it if it helps solving the problem.

I checked various related locations and here is what I found - no android.bat, SDK Manager or AVD Manager. While I am surely interested in finding how they disappeared all of a sudden, I am currently more interested in fixing this issue (AVD and SDK Manager not opening).

C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk
[image]

C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\tools
[image]

C:\Users\thakkap\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\tools\lib
[image]

C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\build-tools
[image]

C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\platform-tools
[image]

Comment: How did you solved it? I'm facing the same problem right now :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably somehow you just lost Android Sdk Tools which was installed before. Just download Android Sdk Tools again and you will be able to open sdk manager. Don't forget to run Android Studio as an administrator.